# QuickTime for Java vs. iTunes DRM

Tags: java, itunes, quicktime, drm

The Apple QuickTime standalone player can manage iTunes' DRM scheme well enough to play movies downloaded from iTunes with no problem.  Is there any way to get QuickTime for Java to handle iTunes DRM similarly well, or is that simply beyond the software's abilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never did find a definitive answer to this, but just in case anybody with a similar question found their way here:  further research suggested that the answer is a resounding **hell** no.  But the standalone QuickTime player has a very rich COM interface; the documentation stinks, but if you crack it open under a COM object browser (like the one that comes with the free version of VB 2008), you can figure it out pretty easily.